# Erlang: C++ bindings state of the art?

Tags: c++, binding, erlang

I'm evaluating binding a C++ project of mine in Erlang. My project uses templates and method overloading massively, so it's not uncommon to have something like this:

```
template <typename T, class Iterator = BufferIterator<T> >
class Buffer
{

public:
    [...]
private:
    [...]
};
```

I've heard that the computational model in Erlang is a bit different from "traditional" programming languages. In Erlang a node seems to be a first class component with messages that flows from a Node from another. In this scenario, is possible, for example: "This is a list of int. Send it to the C++ node, which will convert it into a Buffer<int> object, perform some operations on it, and them convert back the result into a new Erlang list"?
I've seen on the web some project like tinch++, it seems promising but not stable at all.
Every kind of tips, link or code snippet would be very appriciated.

Thanks in advance, A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Interoperability Tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/introduction.html).

For interfacing with C and C++, you don't need to create a node. Port drivers or NIFs (natively implemented functions) may be a better choice. At any rate, your C++ node/port driver/NIF will receive messages/arguments from Erlang as a specific data structure: `ETERM`, `ErlDrvTerm`, or `ERL_NIF_TERM`. Then you check what the term looks like (e.g. if it's a list of ints), and can convert it to whatever you need.